# Is it possible to insert php time() value by default in a column of a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, time

my simple question is .. Is it possible to insert **php** `time()` value by default in a column of a  MYSQL database  so that everytime i don't need to insert it. I know MYSQL provide `CURR_TIMESTAMP`..but they are not stored as integer unlike the time function which gives the timestamp as integer..

Any help will be greatly appreciated... Thanks

Comment: It's really bad habit to store a "time" as integer when the database supports the 'time' format. If you really need it as an integer later (and you should ask why - maybe something else is broken), you can always still convert it.

Comment: Are you actually referring to the time from the server PHP runs at as opposed to the clock of the database server?

Comment: i have the unixtimestamp and i need to run a between query ... and if the stored format is like that then i need to query in another way

Comment: The between query should work the same way regardless of which flavor of date/time datatype you use.

Comment: @Salman A  --> yes you are correct

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
drop table if exists file_events;

create table file_events (
  id int unsigned auto_increment not null,
  file_id int unsigned not null,
  event_time int unsigned not null default UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),    # the field that defaults to "now"
  primary key(id),
  constraint foreign key fk_file_events_to_sam_files (file_id) references files(id) on delete cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `NOW()` are exactly the same, so this doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Matthew: you where right , i've edited my answer , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returns what OP whanted .

Comment: A `timestamp` column is only another type of date, it's not an integer. If you try to store the result of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` (which *is* an integer) all you can get is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on a mysql bases you can always use triggers [ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html ] just create a trigger to set the column of your choice to the current timestamp

Comment: This is the valid answer given the question. Of course, it probably makes more sense to just store a proper date and use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to make the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You should just stick with the MySQL timestamp and convert it as needed. It is easy to do...

```
strtotime("put the mysql timestamp here");
```

will produce the same format (unix timestamp) as

```
time();
```

Comment: well yes thats true... i have the unixtimestamp and i need to run a between query ... and if the stored format is like that then i need to query in another way...

Comment: Note that PHP's time and MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` *both* represent seconds since the UNIX epoch.  See MySQL's [overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many other DBMS, MySQL doesn't support functions as default values. The only exception is the one you mention: dates accept `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or one of their values). It appears to me that's quite an acceptable solution anyway since you can easily convert your Unix timestamp on-the-fly:

```
SELECT foo_id, foo_info
FROM foo
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(1294133369)<=foo_date
```

Or, from PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT foo_id, foo_info
    FROM foo
    WHERE '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1294133369) . "')<=foo_date";
```

Whatever, if you absolutely need to store dates as integers, you must write your own triggers. Here's a nice example:

http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2006/01/playing-with-triggers.html